# XMLHttprequest post method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to send file through xmlhttprequest.send(file) in rails , post method not calling respective action(method) in the controller , get method calling the same action which specified in the post method  and how to get the request(body) content in the controller ?

Any idea?

Comment: I recommend adding more information in your question -- how far have you already gotten? Recommend post some relevent code snippets of your controller/view/model

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from your request object.  Maybe something like this:

path = "public/"
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| 
f.write(request.body.read) 
}